# Howto configure camel/spring JMS for exactly once in order processing (EOIO)?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-jms, oracle-aq

I am trying to realize a exactly once in order processing of JMS messages (consumed from an Oracle Advanced Queue - but this shouldn't matter).

For testing purposes I've created the following route:

```
    <route id="inputAqTest12">
        <from id="_fromAqTest12" uri="aqTest12:queue:QUEPOSTDATA?transacted=true"/>
        <transacted id="_transactedAqTest12"/>
        <!-- Simulate exceptions! -->
        <when id="_when1">
            <simple>${random(10)} == 0</simple>
            <throwException exceptionType="java.lang.Exception"
                id="_throwException1" message="Random error!"/>
        </when>
        <to .../>
    </route>
```

This works as expected as long as my Oracle queue is configured for immediate re-delivery of rejected messages. But I want to have retry delay greater than zero so that the message survives the outage of a back-end system for several minutes - without 'endless' unsuccessful attempts.

So what I'm looking for is the possibility to delay the retrieval of the next message in case of a rollback of the transaction. What I have found is that the spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer has a waitBeforeRecoveryAttempt() method that is called if message processing fails (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java#L1070). But unfortunately this only happens after the second failure in a row; I think I need the delay already after the first rollback, so that I'm able to gain EOIO by configuring the delay after an rollback on the jms consumer to e.g. 10 seconds, but the retry_delay of the oracle advanced queue to a lower value (e.g. 5 seconds).

Maybe I'm also on the wrong track - so any idea how-to realize EOIO behavior for a spring/camel JMS consumer is welcome. Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: Instead of failing the route and the transaction immediately, can you not make use of a Camel error handler with an adequately configured [redelivery policy](http://camel.apache.org/redeliverypolicy.html)?

Comment: Hi Ralf, thanks for your comment, for sure this would result in the desired behavior somehow, but still leaves the problem open that if the target system is unavailable also redelivery fails at some time - and if this happens events are out of order - or did I miss something? For sure I could configure Oracle for immediate redelivery and delay the processing in case of errors with the redelivery policy (I think this is the way to go; but still it's not 100% what I want because could lead to a lot of unsuccessful attempts on subscribers that didn't have a adequate delay).

Comment: You can set the redelivery policy to retry indefinitely and use a (capped) exponential backoff to avoid re-trying at a needlessly high frequency.